# fold all other scopes

Tags: vim, folding

is there a trick to fold all other functions but not the function in there my cursor is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a normal-mode map like this:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>f zMzO
```

The `zM` closes all folds in the current file (which will fold the current function), then the `zO` recursively opens the fold under the cursor (which will unfold the current function).

This assumes you've `:set foldmethod=syntax`; it won't necessarily work as well with other types of folding.